# Proving that $at+b$ and $ct+d$ are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am working with linear fraction transformations, and while reading a proof, I saw that the polynomials $at+b$ and $ct+d$ over a field $k$ are coprime if and only if $ad \ne bc$.

I can't see why this is true, however. I'd really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: What is $t$ a natural number,integer, what?

Comment: Just a formal indeterminate

Comment: What definition of "coprime" are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(t)\mid at+b$ and $p(t)\mid ct+d$ then $p(t)\mid a(ct+d)-c(at+b)=ad-bc$. Hence, if $ad-bc\neq 0$ then $p(t)$ is constant, i.e., $at+b$ and $ct+d$ are coprime. The converse is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing
$$
1=\alpha(at+b)+\beta(ct+d)
$$
which means
\begin{cases}
a\alpha+c\beta=0 \\
b\alpha+d\beta=1
\end{cases}
If $ad-bc\ne0$, the system (in the unknowns $\alpha$ and $\beta$) has a solution.

However, the two polynomials are coprime also when they are constants (but not both zero) and $ad-bc=0$, in this case. You need to assume that at least one of them is non constant, say $a\ne0$. If $ad-bc=0$, then $d=a^{-1}bc$, so the second equation becomes
$$
b\alpha+\frac{bc}{a}\beta=1
$$
This implies $b\ne0$ and $a\alpha+c\beta=a$, which contradicts $a\alpha+b\beta=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well by polynomial division, the quotient of $\frac{at+b}{ct+d}$ is $\frac{a}{c}$ and the numerator of the remainder is $\frac{bc-ad}{c}$. This remainder is zero when $bc=ad$.